# pip spontaneously downgrades a package

Tags: python, pip

I have a Windows 10 workstation with Python 2.7 and pip 18.0. Some time ago I installed a package, conan 0.26.1. Now, I am upgrading with the command `python -m pip install --upgrade conan==1.4.4`. The upgrade completes successfully (including some dependent packages), the file `C:\Python27\Scripts\conan.exe` has a current timestamp, and `conan --version` reports the new version.

Then, after about 10 or 20 minutes, without me doing anything to the computer, that conan.exe file disappears and is replaced with a conan.exe file with a new timestamp, which reports that it is version 0.26.1. A dependent package is also downrev'ed.

I've added auditing on that file and it appears that somehow a command prompt is running a pip command at the time the change occurs. But I have no idea why or how to stop it.

I don't think I am using virtualenv, and turning off Windows Defender does not help. It also happens right after rebooting.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the culprit was Puppet Agent. Going to Services and stopping Puppet Agent fixed the problem.